# PostgreSQL NOTIFY multiple channels

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to make a script that listens to different two triggers from PostgreSQL and run a script based on which trigger was fired: `trigger_1` or `trigger_2`. Perhaps I do not know how it's exactly called, but I couldn't find any guides based on that.

Here is the base script that I have found and it works for me, but it works only for one trigger.

```py
import select
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("LISTEN trigger_1;")
curs.execute("LISTEN trigger_2;")

while 1:
    if select.select([conn],[],[],5) == ([],[],[]):
        print "Timeout"
    else:
        conn.poll()
        while conn.notifies:
            notify = conn.notifies.pop(0)
            (RUN SOME CODE IF TRIGGER_1 FIRES)
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine as is: I can notify either `trigger_1` or `trigger_2` and the code wakes up and processes the notification. What sort of problem are you having?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that I would like to run a different code for `trigger_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I would like to run a different code for trigger_2

Then you need to inspect the `notify` value you get from `conn.notifies`. It will have a `channel` attribute containing the name of the channel that was notified:

```
import select
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=sandbox user=sandbox password=secret host=localhost port=5432 ')
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("LISTEN trigger_1;")
curs.execute("LISTEN trigger_2;")

while 1:
    print('loop')
    if select.select([conn],[],[],5) == ([],[],[]):
        print ('Timeout')
    else:
        conn.poll()
        while conn.notifies:
            notify = conn.notifies.pop(0)
            if notify.channel == 'trigger_1':
                print('do something for trigger_1')
            elif notify.channel == 'trigger_2':
                print('do something for trigger_2')
```

Comment: I thought there should be a simple solution! Thanks